# Issue in dealing with MediaCodec end of stream

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediacodec

I'm using MediaCodec to decode frames from the packets got from ffmpeg. When end of the stream is reached I signal the codec with NULL packet with BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM set. But the output ends immediately without rendering all the frames, for avc codecs. Here is my code for input and output...

```
public int HwDecoderInputCallback( int size, long pts, int flag ){
        int ret = 0, flags = 0;
        final int TIME_OUT_US = 10000;
        int inputBufIndex = 0;
        try{
            try{
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){

            }
        inputBufIndex = chd.decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIME_OUT_US);
        if( inputBufIndex >= 0 ){
            ByteBuffer inputBuf = inputBuffer[inputBufIndex];
            inputBuf.clear();
            getVideoPacketHW(inputBuf, size);
            chd.decoder.queueInputBuffer( inputBufIndex, 0, size, pts, flag);
        }
        }catch(Exception e1){
            // Irrecoverable errors. Release Media codec and recreate resources.
            videoWindow.glRenderer.restoreVideoSurface();
            ret = -1;   
        }
        return ret;
    } 
public int HwDecoderOutputCallBack(){
        int status = 0;
        final int TIME_OUT_US = 10000;
        try{
        int dec_status = chd.decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIME_OUT_US);
        if( dec_status == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER ){
            Log.i("Candy MediaPlayer","Output try again");
        }else if( dec_status == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED){
            Log.i("Candy MediaPlayer","Output buffer changed");
            outputBuffer = chd.decoder.getOutputBuffers();
        }else if( dec_status == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED){
            Log.i("Candy MediaPlayer","Buffer fmt changed");
        }else if( dec_status < 0){
            Log.i("Candy MediaPlayer","Output buffer index < 0");
        }else{
            if(((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM)!=0)){
                Log.i("Candy MediaPlayer","End of stream.");
                chd.decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(dec_status, false);
                status = 1;
            }else{
            candySyncVideoHW( mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs );
            chd.decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(dec_status, true);
            status = 0;
            }
        }
        }
        catch( Exception e){
            // Irrecoverable errors. Release Media codec and recreate resources.
        videoWindow.glRenderer.restoreVideoSurface();
            }   
            return status;
        }
```

What is wrong with this code... I'm calling these fn:s from an infinite loop, it works fine until I give an empty packet of size zero with BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM set. After this it stops immediately without rendering all the packets.

Comment: What do you mean by "it stops immediately"? Are you getting errors from `dequeueOutputBuffer()`? Is something throwing an exception?

Comment: no, but not rendering all frames...

Comment: So the output side is receiving the buffer with the BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM flag set out of order?